Is it possible to remove elements out of a div using order

Hi all,
I'm trying to create this mockup using ReactJS and I can't seem to make my code work. Notice how the profile pic is beside the search bar on mobile but it's beside the button on tablet and desktop. I tried using order but it didn't work. I also tried inline block but I think I wasn't able to really figure it out because I'm used to using flex box. This is my code
import "./Header.scss";

function Header() {
    return (
        <header className="header">
            <img className="header__logo" src="src/assets/images/BrainFlix-logo.svg" alt="BrainFlix Logo" />
            <div className="header__content">
                <div className="header__search-profile">
                    <input className="header__search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                    <img className="header__profile-pic" src="src/assets/images/Mohan-muruge.jpg" alt="side profile of Mohan" />
                </div>
                <button className="header__button--upload" type="submit">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </header>
    )
}

export default Header;

This is my sass
.header__content {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

    @include tablet {
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
}

.header__search-profile {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;

    @include tablet {
        width: auto;
        order: 1;
    }
}

.header__search-bar {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    background: url('../../assets/icons/search.svg') no-repeat 10px center / 20px 20px;
    font-family: inherit;
    border: $border;
    background-color: $alabaster;
    color: $brainflix-black;
    font-family: inherit;
    resize: none;

    @include tablet {
        width: 100%;
    }

    &::placeholder {
        color: $brainflix-black;
        font-size: 0.8125rem;

        @include tablet {
            font-size: 0.875rem;
        }
    }
}

.header__profile-pic {
    @include avatar-style(2.25rem, 2.25rem, 1rem);
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 10%;
    order: 2;

    @include tablet {
        order: 2;
        margin-left: 1rem;
    }
}

.header__button--upload {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.5rem;
    border: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: $demi;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: $brainflix-blue;
    color: $white;
    cursor: pointer;

    order: 3;

    @include tablet {
        order: 2;
        width: 9.375rem;
        padding: 0 2rem;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}

.button__icon--upload {
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}


You can duplicate the profile to have it in both spots, and you show the correct one on each device

@PauloFernando Makes sense. I'm curious to know if there's another or better way to achieve this

To change the order they should all be siblings. You could make it work like that.

SCSS Adjustments:
Set the default order for .header__profile-pic to 2 for mobile views.
On tablet and larger screens (@include tablet), change the order of .header__profile-pic to 3 to place it beside the button.
Adjust the order of the .header__button--upload on tablet and larger screens to 2 to ensure it appears before the profile picture.
The .header__search-profile container is ordered first on tablet and larger screens to ensure the search bar remains on the left.

I tried that. The .header__profile-pic is in within the .header__search-profile container though so I can't seem to use order to change the placement
